# Trying to get the max value from an INDEX MATCH query

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have tried each of the following formulas to get the highest number when I have a duplicate record.  They both give me what appears to be the same output, but I know of at least one ID# where the response for both is "6" when I am expecting "7".

```
F2 = ID# to look for 
PSStatus!$A = Hour; data ranges from 1 to 7; column is formatted as a number.
PSStatus!$F = ID#s

=INDEX(QUERY(PSStatus!$A$2:$A,,), MATCH(MAX($F2), (QUERY(PSStatus!$F$2:$F,,)),0))

=MAX(INDEX(QUERY(PSStatus!$A$2:$A,,), MATCH($F2, (QUERY(PSStatus!$F$2:$F,,)),0)))
```

Comment: Still hoping for help on this.  I've created the same spreadsheet with 'dummy' data.  The basic question is why "Brandon Burgess", who is in two classes (RO100 & R410 see: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…), not appearing as R410 ("7") in the Master spreadsheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaqHCeu1I8v23scElO8DhhBFB1siEhQpqpGHVOQJ804/edit#gid=1456024845

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your data table looks like the following one. Please, forgive me if I am mistaken.

[image: Data table]

If my assumption is correct, you can use the formula `=MAX(FILTER({DATA TABLE RANGE}, {ID COLUMN FROM DATA TABLE}={ID}))`. That formula will first use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to pick only the requested ID and then [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) will pick the highest one. In my example above, the formula should be `=MAX(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$26, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26=A2))` for the first row. This is the end result:

[image: Results table]

Please, ask me anything if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  Please stay safe.

Comment: Your suggestion may work, but I can't figure out how...  The way I have it set up is similar to what you supposed, but different in some critical ways.

Comment: Right now, we are working on column "J" in a sheet called "Master".  "J" gets its data by calling on a sheet named "PSStatus" and comparing its data with "Master"s data in column "F" (a unique ID number) and returning the correlating data from "PSStatus" column "A".    As written, both formulas seem to do a great job of returning the first hit they find in column "A".      I can't figure out how to successfully encourage the INDEX-MATCH QUERY to look at all of the possible outcomes and pick the MAX value.

Comment: Hello @JoshuaReitz! I can't imagine how you wrote your sheet reading your comment, please forgive my lack of imagination. Please, share a sheet online (with fake data) and I will use it to write a formula adapted to your situation.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaqHCeu1I8v23scElO8DhhBFB1siEhQpqpGHVOQJ804/edit#gid=1456024845

Comment: I've paired it down to just three made up names.  Why is "Brandon Burgess", who is in two classes (RO100 & R410 see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaqHCeu1I8v23scElO8DhhBFB1siEhQpqpGHVOQJ804/edit#gid=406113957), not appearing as R410 ("7") in the Master spreadsheet?